# MDADM 5 Disk RAID 10 no spare device created

Tags: linux, mdadm, centos-8

Created a 5 disk RAID 10 by running`mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=10 --raid-devices=5 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sd[d-g]1` and because it was an odd number I expected 1 disk to become a spare device.

However there is 0 spare devices `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`:

```
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 01:23:44 2020
        Raid Level : raid10
        Array Size : 1464820224 (1396.96 GiB 1499.98 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 585928192 (558.78 GiB 599.99 GB)
      Raid Devices : 5
     Total Devices : 5
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Fri Jun  5 03:38:38 2020
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 5
   Working Devices : 5
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : near=2
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : localhost-test1:0  (local to host localhost-test1)
              UUID : 70b93b43:fbf9aebc:710c8153:a29cbd47
            Events : 1565

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       1       8       49        1      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       2       8       65        2      active sync   /dev/sde1
       3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
       4       8       97        4      active sync   /dev/sdg1
```

Isnt it the default policy to create two 2disk mirrors?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the answer is but to move around this there are two options. Fail and remove the drive, grow/lower raid device count, and re-add the drive. Or remove and recreate the array with new parameters. However some sort of delta/resync will happen which will take longer(double the time?) than if you just start from scratch.

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdg1
mdadm /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sdg1
wipefs -a /dev/sdg1
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=4
You may get a warning telling you what to run
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=4
mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdg1
```

Second option is to recreate and specify 1 fewer --raid-devices and explicitly specify the --spare-devices= number and partition:

`mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=10 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sd[d-f]1 --spare-devices=1 /dev/sdg1`